# ChatBot with HTTP routing capabilities

Tags: open-source, python, javascript, java, chat

I got a simple idea around an automated issue agent and I would like to put it into real world.

It should be a ***ChatBot*** application that will *get requests* sent by another application (say Rest HTTP requests) and that will either *respond with a message* or *redirect the request* to another system (should be another Rest HTTP call as well).

Can anybody recommend a library or framework that can offer alike features (preferably a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [java](/questions/tagged/java) one)*?

I am looking for the most straightforward library for the moment but certainly open to any suggestion even for a more sophisticated one.

*Through my researches, the best I could come with was [hubot](https://github.com/hubotio/hubot).*